# Change height of Bootstrap slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, slider

I've tried it with changing the css, I can change the width of it by making a div around it and give it a width of 80% for example. But I can't change the height on that way. Anyone an idea how to change the height? See link below.

Ps. Can't copy the link in snippet or without spacebar.. Sorry for that.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/ZbGwqe/

Js:

```
var $item = $('.carousel .item'); 
var $wHeight = $(window).height();
$item.eq(0).addClass('active');
$item.height($wHeight); 
$item.addClass('full-screen');

$('.carousel img').each(function() {
  var $src = $(this).attr('src');
  var $color = $(this).attr('data-color');
  $(this).parent().css({
    'background-image' : 'url(' + $src + ')',
    'background-color' : $color
  });
  $(this).remove();
});

$(window).on('resize', function (){
  $wHeight = 200;
  $item.height($wHeight);
});

$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 6000,
  pause: "false"
});
```

Comment: You can't because you use background images instead of image tags.

Answer (score 0):

It's coded with javascript so

Change

```
var $wHeight = $(window).height();
$(window).on('resize', function (){
  $wHeight = $(window).height();
  $item.height($wHeight);
});
```

By

```
var $wHeight = 200; // >------- your wanted height
$(window).on('resize', function (){
  $wHeight = 200;   // >------- your wanted height
  $item.height($wHeight);
});
```

CodePen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mRGeoR